# Android MediaPlayer RTSP session timeout

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, vlc, libvlc

I am developing an Android application for streaming local video files from one device to another.

Streaming is done via RTSP using libvcl on the server device and Android MediaPlayer on the client device.

I encountered the following problem: almost a minute after connecting the client, it disconnects due to the session timeout.
I tried specifying media parameters in libvlc: rtsp-timeout and: rtp-timeout, but the timeout does not change.

Is it possible to support an RTSP session through Android MediaPlayer or increase or remove the timeout of an RTSP session in libvlc?

LOG contains

```
2020-03-05 12:53:28.460 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: connection request completed with result 0 (Success)
2020-03-05 12:53:28.483 714-20707/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
2020-03-05 12:53:28.484 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: DESCRIBE completed with result 0 (Success)
2020-03-05 12:53:28.484 714-20707/? I/ASessionDescription: a=control:rtsp://192.168.1.176:8008/test
2020-03-05 12:53:28.485 714-20707/? I/ASessionDescription: a=control:rtsp://192.168.1.176:8008/test/trackID=0
2020-03-05 12:53:28.485 714-20707/? I/ASessionDescription: a=control:rtsp://192.168.1.176:8008/test/trackID=1
2020-03-05 12:53:28.526 714-20707/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
2020-03-05 12:53:28.528 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: SETUP(1) completed with result 0 (Success)
2020-03-05 12:53:28.528 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: server specified timeout of 60 secs.
2020-03-05 12:53:28.565 714-20707/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
2020-03-05 12:53:28.566 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: SETUP(2) completed with result 0 (Success)
2020-03-05 12:53:28.566 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: server specified timeout of 60 secs.
2020-03-05 12:53:28.611 714-20707/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
2020-03-05 12:53:28.613 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: PLAY completed with result 0 (Success)
2020-03-05 12:53:33.575 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: Time now established for all tracks.
2020-03-05 12:54:22.592 714-20707/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
2020-03-05 12:54:22.593 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: OPTIONS completed with result 0 (Success)
2020-03-05 12:54:28.588 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: received BYE on track index 0
2020-03-05 12:54:28.588 714-20707/? I/RTSPSource: received BYE on track index 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to increase the timeout of an RTSP session (server side). 
To do this, pass the –rtsp-timeout parameter to libvlc.

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.add("--rtsp-timeout=600"); //  Timeout in 10 minutes.
LibVLC mLibVLC = new LibVLC(this, options);
```